# Ruby strftime in UK format i.e. dd/mm/yy

Tags: ruby, strftime

I know I can do `@something.created_at.strftime('%d/%m/%y')` to get the date in **dd/mm/yy** format, but it's a pain.

American users however just need to do a simple: `@something.created_at.strftime('%x')`, which gives **mm/dd/yy**.

Is it possible to rig `%x` to work *the proper way*, i.e. the British way (since we invented time).

Comment: Is this a Rails question?

Comment: You want some thing like %x which gives date/month/year in ruby?

Comment: there is no such format in short notation, I would suggest to write a helper method to wrap `.strftime('%d/%m/%y')`

Comment: I think we have. How about .strftime('%D') in ruby?

Comment: @stefan, yes, kind of, although I imagine it will work without Rails since strftime is from standard lib

Comment: Kranthi, `%D` gives US format. Cheers though.

Comment: In a view, you could use Rails' `l` helper.

Comment: `Is it possible to rig %x to work the proper way, i.e. the British way (since we invented time).` Best joke so far in 2016! :)

Comment: No seriously, everyone knows that without the British, everything would have happened in the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *correct* way of doing this now is:

```
# in config/locales/en.yml
date:
  formats:
    default:
      "%d/%m/%y"
```

Then in the view:

```
= l Date.current
```

Yep, that's it. The **l** method is shorthand for I18n.localize. Read more in the [Rails I18n guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats).

Comment: You might want to tag the question with [tag:ruby-on-rails] since this doesn't apply for plain Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

If this is something you are going to use often you could use a Proc:

```
def brit_date
  Proc.new 
end

proc = brit_date {Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%y")}
proc.call
 => "24/11/14"
```

Answer (score -1):

Have look at 
[**easy_dates gem**](https://github.com/platform45/easy_dates)

```
gem install gemcutter
gem tumble
gem install easy_dates
```

you don't have to worry about formatting your dates continually with [**strftime**](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime).